# How do I write a TSV file scraper, where "if line contains x, then save"?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, data-extraction

I want to open a TSV (tab-separated-value) file, and save specific rows to a new CSV (comma-separated-value) file.

If the row contains `'NLD'` in a field with the header 'Actor1Code', I want to save the row to a CSV; if not, I want to iterate to the next row. This is what I have so far, but apparently that is not enough:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("path/to.csv", "wb") do |csv| #csv to save to
  CSV.open('data.txt', 'r', '\t').each do |row| #csv to scrape
    if row['Actor1Code'] == 'NLD'
      csv << row
    else
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Try with `"\t"`, double quotes.

Comment: I tried with double quotes, still doesn't work. Perhaps it has to do with the .txt extension?

Comment: error code: `in 'initialize': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1342:in 'open'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1342:in 'open'
 from code/csv_code/csv_protestscraper_c.rb:5:in 'block in <main>'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1354:in 'open'
 from code/csv_code/csv_protestscraper_c.rb:3:in '<main>`

Comment: `CSV` doesn't know about headers unless add code or options provided to manage them. That is probably what you need help with. The error is complaining about using a `String` to access an item in the row `Array`. If you added a simplified (2-3 column, 2-3 row) sample from your file to the question, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you're calling `CSV.open` correctly? [The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) seems to suggest arguments are passed in as hashes:

```
CSV.open('data.txt', 'r', col_sep: "\t")
```

The error you're seeing is probably the result of `'\t'` being interpreted as a hash and referenced with `[]`.

Comment: Alright, I changed it to , :col_sep: "\t". It gives me a new error: `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
  CSV.open("1990_reduced.tsv", "r", :col_sep "\t") do |row|`

Comment: Syntax is extremely important. I'm using the Ruby 1.9 hash notation `col_sep: "\t"`, but you've done it as an incomplete older style: `:col_sep => "\t"`. Details like that can't be overlooked.